# Largest set of $k$-wise linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb F_q^n$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra

What is known about the largest set of $k$-wise linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb F_q^n$? I am especially interested when $q=2$, and in the regime where $k$ is fixed an $n\to\infty$. Here are some partial results:

- The largest pairwise independent set has $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ vectors.
- The largest size of a $3$-wise independent set is at most $$\frac{q^{n-1}-1}{q-1}+1.$$ To see why, if $S$ is $3$-wise independent, and ${\bf v}_0\in S$, then the set of vectors of the form $a{\bf v}_0+b{\bf v}$ with $a\in \mathbb F_q, b\in \mathbb F_q^{\times}, {\bf v}\in S\setminus\{v_0\}$ are pairwise distinct. This is achieved when $q=2$ by the set of vectors with an odd number of ones. 
   The next simplest case is $q=3$, where I am stuck. It seems to be that finding a large independent set is related to finding a large cap-set in $\mathbb F_3^{n-1}$, which is a hard open problem. Specifically, by multiplying all the vectors in $S$ with an appropriate scalar, you can assume their leftmost nonzero coordinate is $1$, and then if $u,v,w$ all have their first coordinate equaling $1$, then $\{u,v,w\}$ being linearly independent is equivalent $\{u',v',w'\}$ being non-colinear, where $u'$ is obtained by deleting the initial $1$ from $u$, and similarly for $v',w'$.
- Any $4$-wise independent set $S$ must satisfy
  $$
  (q-1)^2\binom{|S|}2\le q^n,
  $$
  which follows by realizing that the vectors of the form $a{\bf v}_1+b{\bf v}_2$, with $a,b\in \mathbb F_q^\times$ and ${\bf v}_1,{\bf v}_2\in S$, are pairwise distinct (for this to work, each pair $\{{\bf v}_1,{\bf v}_2\}$ must appear at most once). This gives $|S|\lesssim \sqrt{2}q^{n/2}/(q-1)$. I am not sure if this the true growth rate, even for $q=2$.
- It seems straightforward to generalize these upper bound arguments to show that the size of a $k$-wise independent set is $\mathcal O(q^{n/\lfloor k/2\rfloor})$.

To summarize, I am wondering if the upper bounds I gave are tight, and if any other general constructions are known. (The reason for the [pr.probability](/questions/tagged/pr.probability) is that $k$-wise independent vectors give rise to $k$-wise independent sets of random variables, which is how I came across this problem).

Comment: Though it has been two years since you asked the question, you might be interested in our coming paper. Recently, we are working with an essentially equivalent problem and able to show that there is a $k$-wise linearly independent set of $\Omega(2^{n/[k/2]})$ vectors. We also prove some non-trivial lower bound for general $q$, that beat the gready trivial lower bound.

Comment: I have been yearning to see a solution to this problem for a long time, so yes, I would be very interested in reading your paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\F}{{\mathbb F}}$
Let's focus on the case $q=2$ which you are primarily interested in. Suppose that $v_1,\dotsc,v_m\in\F_2^n$, and let $V$ be the matrix over $\F_2$ of size $n\times m$ with $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ (written in the standard basis) as its columns. It is readily seen that for $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ to be $k$-wise linearly independent, it is necessary and sufficient that the kernel of $V$ did not contain any vector of weight $k$ or less. You are thus asking how large can the length $m$ of a linear code be given that the minimum distance of the code is at least $k+1$, and that the code has co-dimension $n$. This is essentially equivalent to the central problem of coding theory: what is the largest possible dimension of a linear code of given length and minimum distance ($m$ and $k+1$, respectively, in our case)?

Comment: To add to this, a keyphrase for the OP is the "Gilbert–Varshamov bound".